# Binary or string data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running an insert statement to populate records into a table using SQL Server 2012. In table 1 that has all the records, the datatype is VARCHAR(5000), and I have done a max(len) to determine that the maximum length of data it contains is about 3000.

In table 2 that the records should go into, the datatype for the field is VARCHAR(5000), which mirrors what's in Table 1.

I am getting the dreaded binary or string data would be truncated message, but my destination table field is large enough to store this data.

When I remove this field from the insert statement, the insert statement works fine and my data moves from Table 1 to Table 2 as expected, but including the field causes this error.

Has anyone come across this peculiar case before? Is it possible that the string field has some sort of weird characters in it that could be causing this error.

Thanks

Comment: Trailing spaces are ignored by `LEN()`, you can try if `DATALENGTH()` gives a different result.

Comment: Please show the table schemas, `insert` statement, and output of `max()` of both `len()` and `datalength()`.

Comment: If the target data type and max length is exactly the same as the source data type and max length, you shouldn't be getting this message. Double check. (perhaps one is `varchar` and the other `nvarchar`?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. The answer by HoneyBadger is a winner. DATALENGTH() reveals that the length is much longer than expected, as there are a lot of trailing spaces